# Uploading data to google colab comes as dictionary, unlike uploading to notebook. Why is this?

Tags: google-colaboratory

How can I change the dictionary to dataframe in colab?

I added two pictures. One from colab and the other from notebook.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9yMf.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcY8T.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your notebook you have read your data using Pandas library

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

And that's why you it was uploaded as dataframe. While the `files.upload()` funstion it uplodes your files as dictionary and you need to read it as dataframe. However, you just need to read your data again after it has been uploeded using

```
data = pd.read_csv('DailyDelhiClimateTest.csv.csv')
```

Best of luck :)